# Как обратиться к объекту?

Tags: android, kotlin

помогите разобраться, есть код:

```
    button.addListener(object : InputListener() {
        override fun touchDown(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
            object : Dialog("window") {
                init {
                    ...
                }
            }
            .show()
            .addListener(object : InputListener() {
                override fun touchDown(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
                    if (...) {
                    ??-->> dialog.hide()
                    }
                    return true
                }
            });                
        }
    }
```

как в нем правильно написать строчку `dialog.hide()`, чтобы обратиться к созданному объекту? (Dialog("window"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Надо рефакторить код, чтобы была ссылка на немутабельный объект.
Типа такого:

```
        val dialog = object : Dialog("window") {
            init {
                ...
            }
        }
        dialog.show()
        dialog.addListener(object : InputListener() {
            override fun touchDown(event: InputEvent?, x: Float, y: Float, pointer: Int, button: Int): Boolean {
                if (...) {
                    dialog.hide()
                }
                return true
            }
        })
```